# Greek or Latin word to express "revealing the sacred in the mundane?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom, greek-to-english-translation

Greetings from a newbie with a very limited knowledge of Latin and less of Greek - some from working in the sciences and more from obsessive reading of English etymologies.

I'm seeking a word in either language - or a chimaera - that extends the *hierophant* concept from *making known that which is sacred* to *showing how the commonplace is itself sacred*. Something like "hieroendokoinophant," but a little less clunky, would be nice. I have read only the usual non-major undergrad classics, in English, and have not run across such a term. But the concept has surely been expressed by many.

A plausible neologism would be fine - I make them myself all the time, and sometimes they even turn out to be pre-existing and legitimate! (Like when one of my university professors used the word trifurcate. I checked the OED to see if it was real - which it is - and asked if he'd known that. He said no, but that it seemed to fit. So now I feel licensed to do likewise.)

Not important, not for a term paper; just looking for a poetic way to encapsulate a treasured world-view. All thoughts, including redirections, much appreciated.